# Internationalization of javascript strings in a Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a rails application, which has some strings inside the assets / javascripts files, how can I internationalize these strings? Note: I can't use the rails I18n, because I can't add the .erb extension to these javascript files, so I can't use ruby ​​code on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to write a simple rails task that generates a JavaScript file containing translations.

```
namespace :translations do
  desc "Create a JavaScript File containing translations"
  task :generate => :environment do
    locale = ARGV[1] || I18n.default_locale
    keys = ['hello', 'goodbye'] # ...
    I18n.with_locale(locale) do
      data = Hash[keys, keys.map { |k| I18n.t!(k) }]
    end
    begin
      f = File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets/javascript/translations.js') , 'w')
      f.write("export default #{data.to_json}")
    ensure
      f.close
    end
  end
end
```

This would create an ES6 module that looks like this:

```
export default {
  hello: 'Ola',
  goodbye: 'Tchau'
}
```

Which you then import where you need it:

```
import Translations from 'translations';
```

If you're not using Webpack you could use the same approach with Sprockets  but it don't really see the point as it will process ERB files which is a much simpler solution. You could also potentially use the ERB loader for Webpack to do this.

Comment: Yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules. If you dont want to use ES6 modules you could use something else like a global.

Comment: And its just a simple object so you just do `Translations["hello"]`.

Comment: Also i need to have one file each language, it can't be a single file for all.

Comment: `Rails.root.join('app/assets/javascript/', "translations-#{locale].js")`. `locale` is here is the first argument to the rake task for  example `rake translations:generate fr`. And then you would do `import French from 'translations-fr';`

Comment: this is what happens when I run rake command: 
I18n::MissingTranslationData: translation missing: pt-BR.hello

Comment: You do realize that this is just an outline of an approach and that you'll actually have to adapt it to your specific use case?

Comment: So, in this case the rake task will just map the rails i18n keys in a way that I can use with javascript right? I think I got it.

Comment: Yes. This simplefied example will just translate `['hello', 'goodbye']`. In normal use you would probally want to find a YAML file and translate all the keys.

Comment: Looks like import isn't working as it should, it just messes with my other functions and return nothing. Since I have a old project using ruby 1.9.3 I can't use gems like i18n-js to deal with it. No idea what i'll have to do in order to make this work. Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: Just use a global in the file instead then?  `f.write("window.Translations = window.Translations || {}; window.Translations['#{locale}'] = #{data.to_json};")`

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) for doing this. You can add your strings to one of the translation yml files and access them in the exact same way as you do on the Rails side.